# Connecting to Snowflake from R Workbench using Okta

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, okta

Our Snowflake is setup as SSO login via Okta. We are having issues connecting to SnowFlake via Okta from a R session (in Workbench).

Scenario 1:

We have authenticator as Snowflake and this works FINE.

```r
myconn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "SnowflakePRD", uid="username@company.com", PWD="secret_password", authenticator = "snowflake")
```

Scenario 2:

When we have the authenticator as Okta like this we run into issues:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
  "SnowflakePRD",  
  "jdbc:snowflake://company.snowflakecomputing.com/?authenticator=https://company.okta.com/",
  "username@company.com")
```

> Error in OdbcConnection(dsn = dsn, ..., timezone = timezone, timezone_out = timezone_out,  :
> all(has_names(args)) is not TRUE

We tried adding the time zone of the Workbench server (UTC) in the code, still the same error.

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
  "SnowflakePRD",  
  "jdbc:snowflake://company.snowflakecomputing.com/?authenticator=https://compnay.okta.com/",
  username@company.com,
  timezone=”UTC”,
  timezone_out=”UTC”)
```

> Error in OdbcConnection(dsn = dsn, ..., timezone = timezone, timezone_out = timezone_out,  :
> all(has_names(args)) is not TRUE

We recently got to know that we use external browser for authentication.  Okta is in sync with Active directory. It validates with Active directory and logs us in.

For this case, does the user still need a password to log in?

Please let me know what is missing?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide what error is seen when using Okta authenticator and maybe a screenshot for it?

Comment: As I see you're using ODBC driver to connect. What is this for ""jdbc:snowflake://company.snowflakecomputing.com" then?

Comment: I am giving that jdbc line to specify the authenticator as Okta.  I tried removing the jdbc and having just authenticator = “company.Okta.com” . Still get error as failed to connect to Okta. Error code 401.

Comment: @Srinath when I use Okta authenticator I get Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [RStudio][Snowflake] (30) Failed to connect to okta. Error code=401